# Why does the object class methods take instances of class as their parameters

Tags: java

To explain my question, in below code why do I have to pass object/instance of a class just to see how toString method is being overridden and why does the toString method, doesn't have parameter of type class to accept that object ?

```
Class Teacher

{

         public String toString()

         {

            return("Hello")
         }
}
```

```
Class TestTeacher

{

          public static void main(String []arr)
          {
               Teacher obj = new Teacher();
                System.out.println(obj);
          } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why do I have to pass object/instance of a class just to see how toString method is being overridden

You do not need to pass the object to the `toString` method, you can just call

```
Teacher obj = new Teacher();
String output = obj.toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

> and why does the toString method have an parameter of type class to accept that object ?

It has not. I think you are confused because you call the normal println function with the object. In turn internally the `toString` function is called to be able to print something to the standard output. So the object here is not the parameter of `toString` but is the parameter of the `println` function.

Comment: Thank you Bas .. but why is the object of a class being passed to the toString method instead of just the string ?

Comment: The object is passed to the println function (not the tostring). This is just a shorthand notation, when println detects that you want to print an object it calls the object's toString function.

Comment: Thank you so much ... Now i can stop banging my head on the computer :)

Comment: Does it really need of conversion `obj.toString()`? shall i print directly `System.out.println(obj);` without conversion.

Comment: It does not Need conversion, it was just to explain how it works.